# what does curlftpfs with fuse option do when mounting to this QNAP NAS

Tags: fstab

my /etc/fstab on a Ubuntu 20.04 system has the following line, minus some details that I wish to hide:

```
curlftpfs#<admin-user>:<PASSWORD>@192.168.<NAS>:<port> /srv/html/data fuse auto,user,uid=33,gid=0,umask=0007,allow_other,_netdev 0 0
```

where <NAS> are subnet and address to my network storage drive (Qnap TS-453A),
<admin-user> is an account on the NAS box with admin privileges
<password> is obvious.

Background: I've lost my IT person and I'm left trying to support my servers until I can find a replacement.  I'm not familiar with how curlftpfs works but I understand that it mounts remote files from the NAS machine on the local machine. Sure enough I see files accessible at /srv/html/data.

However, when I access the NAS html UI and use available tools I can't find where the files are stored. I want to better understand this so I can update the drives since they are getting full.

My question is: can we tell from this fstab line what the mount point is in the QNAP NAS that corresponds to /srv/html/data files?

Comment: Not with certainty. You need to look at the FTP settings on the NAS to see if the FTP user is jailed in some directory. If the NAS supports containers, then the FTP service might be set up manually in the container and not via the NAS device's admin panel.